# Firebug not stopping on exceptions or debugger statements

Tags: firefox, firebug, javascript-debugger

I can't remember the last time I had Firebug completely working, but I now have a strong need for it. I'm trying to catch some particularly deceptive JavaScript errors using console debugging and `debugger;` statements.

For one thing, both Chrome and IE are very easily able to stop upon any JavaScript error - either inside a try/catch, or not. With Firebug, in no unusual circumstances does it simply print the error to the console and continue on. The pause icon on the Console tab is already enabled (tried in both states).

Furthermore, the `debugger;` statement doesn't do a thing - Firebug completely ignores it in any circumstance.

I can add breakpoints to code files, though that doesn't help my situation. At the moment, even IE10's debugging tools are far more useful to me. I've tried reinstalling Firebug, resetting my settings, and even reverting back to Firebug version 1.11.1. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have the same problem in the integrated dev tools ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the integrated tools don't find the script files I'm loading (possibly because of the loader library I use), and they're very slow - the page takes a very long time to load while the dev tools are open. Plus, the console intermittently does nothing. (5 + 7: <no response>)